# How can I use the glfwgetkeycallback function inside of a class?

Tags: c++, input, callback, glfw

glfwGetKey always returns true while the key is pressed instead of just once.

This does not happen in the callback function, but how can I implement it inside of a Input class, so that I can modify a field in that class?

```
class Input {
    GLFWwindow* window;
    float up;
public:
    Input(GLFWwindow * window) {
        this->window = window;
    }

    static void key_callback(GLFWwindow* window, int key, int scancode, int action, int mods)
    {
        if (key == GLFW_KEY_W && action == GLFW_PRESS) {
            up = true;
        }
        else
        {
            up = false;
        }
    }

    float vertical() {  
        glfwSetKeyCallback(window, key_callback);
        return up;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 2):

It's common among C-libraries to associate an user defined pointer with an object. Use `glfwSetWindowUserPointer` to set user data on the window, in this case the `this` pointer, and retrieve it with `glfwGetWindowUserPointer`. Have a look at the reference:
https://www.glfw.org/docs/3.3/group__window.html#ga3d2fc6026e690ab31a13f78bc9fd3651

Comment: How would I use this to solve the problem?

Comment: you set the user pointer to an instance of Input (this), then in the static function you receive the user pointer from the passed window instance, cast it to Input and call the member function